# Generic type in interface method Java

Tags: java, generics, methods, interface

I have this method in my interface:

```
  public String getValue();
```

String is just for the example here, I don't want to return  a String.

And I want to put the method in classes that will return ints, chars or bools (depending on the class). For example, I have a class Animal that implements my interface and has this method. I want it to return an int when this method is invoked in an animal. I have another class person that has this method, and when this method is invoked on a Person I want it to return a char.

```
public class Animal implements myInterface {
  @Override
  public int getValue() {
    return 5;
  }
}

public class Person implements myInterface {
  @Override
  public char getValue() {
    return 'c';
  }
}
```

I understand I have to do this with generics. But how exactly do I do it?

If I replace String in the interface with a generic type, like:

```
public <T> T getValue();
```

then it says I cannot cast from int (or char) to T.

What should I do? Thanks.

Comment: Sounds like an X/Y problem. What does your interface actually represent?

Comment: I think you should redesign that fact that you have multiple types to represent a "value". If all the classes have a "value", it is expected that they be of the same type. Otherwise, name the variable more appropriately and give it its own setters/getters.

Comment: It should not be the getValue method that is generic but the interface itself.

Comment: It may be because of the fact that you're trying to use primitives. Generics only work with objects / classes

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The proper way to do that is by having a generic interface:

```
public interface MyInterface<T> {
  public T getValue();
}

public class Animal implements MyInterface<Integer> {
  @Override
  public Integer getValue() {
    return 5;
  }
}
```

However, this really reeks like an X/Y problem; not to mention that it's highly inefficient, boxing and unboxing all those primitives.

What are you trying to achieve? What is your goal?

Comment: That's essentially what the OP seemed to be trying.  The "gotcha" is that he needs to use an object type ("Integer"), and not a primitive type ("int").  Only reference types, not primitive types, can be used as generic type arguments.

Answer (score 1):

Actually

```
    public <T> T getValue();
```

can be overridden by

```
    public Character getValue()
```

This is weird ... it was for some [backward-comparability](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.4.5) mumbo jumbo. Don't do it.

---

Usually, we say return types can be covariant, i.e. we can return a subtype in the overriding method. Since `char` is a [subtype](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.10.1) of `int`, we may expect that this should work

```
    public int getValue();

    // overridden by
    public char getValue()
```

however, java [requires](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.4.5) that if the return type is primitive, it must be identical, no covariance there.